downgrade an iPhone to an older iOS version
I'm new to the iOS ecosystem and I had been asked by my company to test our app on an iPhone 11 Pro. Once, I needed to do a factory reset and I forgot to disable automatic updates; the phone auto-upgrade itself to iOS 17.4.1.
Is there a legal/normal way to downgrade to a previous iOS? I don't have enough knowledge on flashing/jail-breaking/other stuff like these, and I don't want to brick the phone (as it's my company property).

Unfortunately not , whether via jailbreaking or "official" methods.
Once Apple releases a new version of iOS, it stops authorizing ("signing") the old one, usually after a short period of time. Without that digital signature, the device will "refuse" to run iOS that isn't signed.
Perhaps someone can chime in with a more technical explanation of how it works on newer devices with SHSH2 Blobs, and whether saving those blobs can continue to downgrade, or whether Apple patched that.
If you're testing an app for development purposes, it's not ideal, but you can test on old iOS versions in the Xcode Simulator.
What version do you want to downgrade to?
